# Having trouble finding the right join statement for my query

Tags: sql

I am trying to export data from a database and am joining the "customers" table with the "orders" table.  It's a one to many relationship where customers can have multiple orders.  I'm trying to write a query that returns basic customer info from the customers table - email_address, firstname, lastname, but to also include the date of the last order they placed.

```
customers as c
 - customer_id
 - firstname
 - lastname
 - email_address

orders as o
 - orders_id
 - customers_id
 - purchase_date
```

I want the result to return a single result for each customer where the purchase date is the last purchase that customer made.

c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email_address, o.purchase_date

What is the correct SQL syntax to make this happen?

Comment: If you can't find a RIGHT JOIN that works, maybe you should try using a LEFT JOIN instead?

Comment: What should happen if the customer has not placed any orders? Are there orders not associated with a customer?

Comment: Did you mean "RIGHT JOIN" or just "correct join"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.*, o.LastOrderDate
from customers c
LEFT JOIN
(select customers_id, max(purchase_date) as LastOrderDate
from orders
group by customers_id) o on o.customers_id=c.customers_id
```

Will get all customers and the date of the last order, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email_address, MAX(o.purchase_date)
  FROM customers AS c
  JOIN orders    AS o ON o.customers_id = c.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email_address
```

This only lists customers who have placed at least one order.  If you want all customers, then you should be able to use a LEFT JOIN instead of a simple (INNER) JOIN as shown.

Answer (score 0):

This returns all Customers, regardless of whether they have any Orders:

```
SQL> select c.name
  2         , c.email_address
  3         , ( select max (o.order_date) from orders o
  4             where o.customer_no = c.customer_no )as last_order
  5  from   customers c
  6  /

NAME                 EMAIL_ADDRESS             LAST_ORDE
-------------------- ------------------------- ---------
ACME Industries      info@acme.com             07-APR-10
Tyrell Corporation   accounts@tyrellcorp.com   26-MAR-10
Lorax Textiles Co    the.lorax@hotmail.com

SQL>
```

It is equivalent to the LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SQL> select c.name
  2         , c.email_address
  3         , o.last_order_date
  4  from   customers c
  5         left join ( select o.customer_no
  6                          , max (o.order_date) as last_order_date
  7                     from orders o
  8                     group by o.customer_no ) o
  9                 on o.customer_no = c.customer_no
 10  /

NAME                 EMAIL_ADDRESS             LAST_ORDE
-------------------- ------------------------- ---------
ACME Industries      info@acme.com             07-APR-10
Tyrell Corporation   accounts@tyrellcorp.com   26-MAR-10
Lorax Textiles Co    the.lorax@hotmail.com

SQL>
```

A RIGHT OUTER JOIN would only return rows for Customers with Orders.  Assuming an Order must have a Customer (i.e. enforced foreign key) then that would be the same as an INNER JOIN.

If your flavour of database supports analytic functions then RANK() offers an alternative way of solving it...

```
SQL> select name
  2         , email_address
  3         , order_date
  4  from (
  5      select c.name
  6             , c.email_address
  7             , o.order_date
  8             , rank () over (partition by c.customer_no
  9                              order by o.order_date desc ) as rnk
 10      from   customers c
 11             join orders o
 12                 on ( o.customer_no = c.customer_no)
 13  )
 14  where rnk = 1
 15  /

NAME                 EMAIL_ADDRESS             ORDER_DAT
-------------------- ------------------------- ---------
ACME Industries      info@acme.com             07-APR-10
Tyrell Corporation   accounts@tyrellcorp.com   26-MAR-10

SQL>
```

This also only returns rows for Customers with Orders.